# Why generic form of groupBy in Kotlin is not enough?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin documentation for `groupBy` shows special form for every type, like `ByteArray`, `IntArray`. Why it is so, why the single generic form is not enough?

```
inline fun <T, K> Array<out T>.groupBy(
    keySelector: (T) -> K
): Map<K, List<T>>
```

The snippet [from Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html)

```
inline fun <T, K> Array<out T>.groupBy(
    keySelector: (T) -> K
): Map<K, List<T>>
inline fun <K> ByteArray.groupBy(
    keySelector: (Byte) -> K
): Map<K, List<Byte>>
inline fun <K> ShortArray.groupBy(
    keySelector: (Short) -> K
): Map<K, List<Short>>
inline fun <K> IntArray.groupBy(
    keySelector: (Int) -> K
): Map<K, List<Int>>

...
```

**Question 2**

It seems like `IntArray` is not subclassing the `Array` and that's probably the reason why it is necessary.

So, I wonder - if I would like to add my own function, let's say `verySpecialGroupBy` - does it means that I would also need to specify not just one such function - but repeat it for every array type?

Or it's a very specific and rare case when you would need to use those special arrays and in practice you can just define your function for generic `Array` and ignore the rest?

Comment: Please ask separate questions in separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Those array specializations are for arrays of primitive types. So in your example of creating a `verySpecialGroupBy` function, you would only need to repeat it for each specialization if you wanted to use it with primitive type arrays.

You can read more about the need of primitive type array in this [Kotlin discussion thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-do-the-primitive-array-classes-need-to-be-exposed/1455).